# Most appropriate API for URL shortening service

Tags: php, api, rest, soap, url-shortener

I've just finished an online service for shortening URLs (in php5 with Zend Framework); you can enter an URL and you get an short URL (like tinyurl and such sites).

I'm thinking about the API for developers - at the moment you can send URLs with SOAP to the service, but I am not sure if this is a good solution. What is the best practice for such a service? REST? SOAP? Both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely REST - the overhead for SOAP is unnecessary unless you're building a particularly secure enterprise URL shortening service (which I think is probably an oxymoron). [The bit.ly API](http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation) is pretty good and worth checking out.

Answer (score 5):

i'd limit myself to rest, because the whole "API" is just two calls (return the long url for short and vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

In this situation I'd say REST all the way, SOAP is overkill for this and gets you nothing other than an increase in network load. The api is simple enough for a textual description to suffice although you might want to look at [WADL](http://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/)

Answer (score 1):

Also voting for REST as SOAP is such a big beast and overkill for this small API. Plus all popular url shortening services use REST. You even should consider being quite next to one of the more popular services as this might help developers to more easily add you service ;)